# MongoServerError - bad auth Authentication failed?

Tags: mongodb

i was tryin to connect with mongodb. it shows me MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
code given below

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
require("dotenv").config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

//mongodb connect

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DATABASE_USER}:${process.env.DATABASE_PASS}@cluster0.zobm7.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
client.connect((err) => {
  const collection = client.db("mac-yard").collection("products");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  console.log("database conected");
  client.close();
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello");
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("listening to port", +port);
});
```

Comment: Why `mongodb+srv://` and not `mongodb://`?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error:

> Server is running on port: 5000
> MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
> at Connection.onMessage (/home/mostafa/documents/local-repositories/mern-mongodb-tutorial/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:202:30)
> at MessageStream. (/home/mostafa/documents/local-repositories/mern-mongodb-tutorial/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:62:60)
> at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
> at processIncomingData (/home/mostafa/documents/local-repositories/mern-mongodb-tutorial/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:108:16)
> at MessageStream._write (/home/mostafa/documents/local-repositories/mern-mongodb-tutorial/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:28:9)
> at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:390:12)
> at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:331:10)
> at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:335:10)
> at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:527:28) {
> ok: 0,
> code: 8000,
> codeName: 'AtlasError',
> [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'HandshakeError' }

**Solution:**
If you've got a `config.env` file in your project server-side directories, where you have put your `ATLAS_URI`
Just login to your https://cloud.mongodb.com account and beside your Cluster name, you will find a green button named `Connect`, There, click on `Connect your application` and copy the connection string. Go back to the `config.env` file and update the ATLAS_URI like below:
`ATLAS_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@sandbox.jadwj.mongodb.net/employees?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

Comment: This did not work for me.  I have the correct connection string, it still gives the same authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

for my case user ID password were right .
but my error was "<>"

mongodb+srv://user:@cluster0

solution >>> No tag
mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You probably already tried this already but I made a new user with the most basic login credentials and this stopped me from getting this error. See link to for support https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvlJGvP18Qk.

From there you can try making a user with your desired details.

Answer (score 0):

for my case,
before running the terminal, i change my password in mongodb.com
so i also change my .env file password.
then i came to this error.
"MongoServerError - bad auth Authentication failed?".
i tried different approach,
i already killed the terminal,
then restart VS code,
then restart my laptop.
still nothing happens,

then i change my password in the .env file to my previous password. then restart the terminal. then it works fine again.